# Is there a way to Enable Verbose logging but hide verbose output?

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, dart

I want to enable verbose logging so that if there's an error I need to report to the Flutter team, I can capture the output, however, I don't want to see all of this since it floods the console with text I don't actually want to see. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds, maybe piping the output elsewhere or are all the logs coming from the same place?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Can you explain the difference between "verbose logging" and "verbose output"?

Comment: Well because they dont use my console output when they want logs, I don't want to see all of it. I think flutter writes its logs in a file somewhere and that's the only place I want it to be, not in my console.